# How dynamically set validation attributes to a Model MVC 2?

Tags: model-view-controller, validation

Lets says I have the following model

```
public class Person 
{
  [NameIsValid]
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

I created a custom attribute NameIsValid for this model.

Lets says for ViewA I need the custom attribute validation in the model, but for ViewB I dont need this custom  validation attribute.

How can I dynamically set or remove the custom attribute from the model when need it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any validation in ViewB :

Client-side :

```
@Html.ValidateFor(x => x.Name)
```

Nor server-side :

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{...}
```